# How do you solve for the particular solution of this differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, fundamental-solution

We were given a differential equation problem and it is somehow mind-boggling that it needed a particular solution. The general solution itself is already very long; let alone a particular solution. Here's the problem. We had to solve:

$$\begin{cases}
x^2(y''-2y'+10y)'' - x(x+4)(y''-2y'+10y)'+2(x+3)(y''-2y'+10y)=0 \\
y(1) = 0, y'(1) = 0, y''(1) = -1, y^{(3)}(1)=25
\end{cases}$$

Is there a better way to solve this? I find my solution pretty ugly. Attached in this post is what I got as the general solution. I had to use WolframAlpha for this because the given is so ridiculous.

[image: First Step]

[image: Second Step]

[image: Last Step]

Comment: How do I get the particular solution because I only got the general solution.

Comment: And is there a better way to solve this differential equation?

Comment: I do not know how to proceed anymore after I got the general solution because it is so long if I take the third derivative of that thing.

Comment: Those were the only pieces of information given to us.

Comment: It isn't written something like $\begin{cases}
x^2(y''-2y'+10y)'' - x(x+4)(y''-2y'+10y)'+2(x+3)(y''-2y'+10y)= \cos 3x \\
y(1) = 0, y'(1) = 0, y''(1) = -1, y^{(3)}(1)=25
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would approach it.

Looking at the equation
$$
x^2 a'' - (x+4) xa' + 2 (x+3)a = 0,
$$
$x^2a''$ and $x a'$ make me want to try a solution of the form $a(x) = x^n b(x)$. Plugging this in and doing some algebra gives
$$
x^2 (b''-b') + (n-2)[2x b'+(n-x-3)b] = 0
$$
Choosing $n = 2$ gives $b'' - b' = 0$, which easily solves to $b(x) = C_2 + C_3 e^x$. So we have $a(x) = x^2(C_2+ C_3 e^x)$. We can then use $a = y'' - 2y' + 10$ and the initial conditions to determine $C_2$ and $C_3$. We have that $a(1) = y''(1) - 2 y(1) + 10y(1) = -1$ and $a'(1) = y'''(1) -2y''(1) + 10 y(1) = 27$. Since $a(1) = C_2 + e C_3$ and $a'(1) = 2 C_2 + 3 e C_3$, we can solve the linear equations to get $C_2 = -30$ and $C_3 = 29/e$. Thus the full solution for $a$ is
$$
a(x) = -30x^2 + 29x^2e^{x-1}.
$$

We return to the differential equation for $y$, now given by
$$
y''-2y' + 10 y = -30x^2 + 29x^2e^{x-1}.
$$
First, we use variation of parameters to find the particular solutions. For the $x^2$ term, choose a quadratic for $y_2$. You can plug it in and solve to get $y_2(x) = -3(x-1/5)(x+3/5)$. For the other term, choose $y_3$ of the form $(ax^2 + bx + c)e^x$ and repeat to get $y_3(x) = 29/81(9x^2 -2)e^{x-1}$. The homogeneous equation is easily solved, so all that's left is to apply the remaining initial conditions. For this, it will be convenient to express things in terms of $u = x-1$, so that the conditions apply at $u = 0$. We have
$$
y(u) = C_0e^{u}\cos(3u) + C_1e^{u}\sin(3u) -3\left(u+\frac{4}{5}\right)\left(u+\frac{8}{5}\right)+\frac{29}{81}(9u^2+18u+7)e^u \\
y(0) = C_0 - \frac{96}{25}+\frac{203}{81} = 0\Longrightarrow C_0 = \frac{2701}{2025}\\
y'(0) = C_0 + 3 C_1 - \frac{36}{5} +\frac{725}{81} = 3C_1 +\frac{694}{225} = 0\Longrightarrow C_1 = -\frac{694}{675} = -\frac{2082}{2025}.
$$
This gives
$$
y(x) = e^{x-1}\frac{2701\cos(3x-3) -2082\sin(3x-3)}{2025} -3\left(x-\frac{1}{5}\right)\left(x+\frac{3}{5}\right)+\frac{29}{81}(9x^2 - 2)e^{x-1}.
$$
It's not the simplest of functions, but it [satisfies the boundary conditions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BD%5BExp%5Bx-1%5D%28%282701Cos%5B3x-3%5D-2082Sin%5B3x-3%5D%29%2F2025-3%2F25%285x-1%29%285x%2B3%29Exp%5B1-x%5D%2B29%2F81%289x%5E2-2%29%29%2C%7Bx%2Cn%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C3%7D%5D%2F.x-%3E1) and [satisfies](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Expand%5BExp%5Bx%5DD%5BExp%5B-x%5DExp%5Bx-1%5D%28%282701Cos%5B3x-3%5D-2082Sin%5B3x-3%5D%29%2F2025-3%2F25%285x-1%29%285x%2B3%29Exp%5B1-x%5D%2B29%2F81%289x%5E2-2%29%29%2Cx%2Cx%5D%2B9Exp%5Bx-1%5D%28%282701Cos%5B3x-3%5D-2082Sin%5B3x-3%5D%29%2F2025-3%2F25%285x-1%29%285x%2B3%29Exp%5B1-x%5D%2B29%2F81%289x%5E2-2%29%29%5D) $y''- 2y'+10 y = e^{x}(e^{-x}y)'' + 9 y = C_2 x^2 + C_3 x^2 e^{x-1}$. (I use the alternate form of the differential operator to stay under WolframAlpha's character limit.)

Also, despite the messiness, your answer is actually equivalent to this. The key is to notice that $$
\frac{C}{81}\left[(9x^2-2)\sin(3x) + 6x\cos(3x)\right]
e^{x}\sin(3x) - \frac{C}{81}\left[(2-9x^2)\cos(3x) + 6x\sin(3x)\right]e^{x}\cos(3x) \\
= \frac{C}{81}\left[\sin^2(3x)+\cos^2(3x)\right](9x^2-2)e^x + \frac{C}{81}\left[\sin(3x)\cos(3x)-\cos(3x)\sin(3x)\right]6x e^x\\
 = \frac{C}{81}(9x^2-2)e^x
$$
And similarly for the $A$ term.

Comment: Brilliant! I never thought of applying the initial conditions right after I get the value of $a(x)$. Very well done.